# Weekday counter skipping the first Monday after a weekend comes

Tags: javascript, counter, weekday

I know similar questions have been asked but I can't seem to find the answer in any of them. So I need to make a weekday counter using only JavaScript. The aim is the count the working days between two dates.

I have it mostly working except that when the starting date falls on a Saturday or Sunday, the following Monday is not counted and the output is short by one day. I know this is happening because the variable count is initialized as 0 and it doesn't increase with the iteration but I don't know what to do to fix that. After this happens though, everything else works completely fine.

I have tried multiple things but I can't seem to figure out what to do. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. I'm pasting the code below for anyone to review.

```
let eta='2020-07-23';
let req='2020-07-31T10:33:21.000Z';
let results;

//uncomment to check if the output is correct
window.alert(weekdayCount(eta,req));

function weekdayCount(d1,d2)
{   
    var tempEndDate = new Date(d2);
    tempEndDate.setHours(0,0,0,1);          //set the end dates time to midnight.
    var startDate = Date.parse(d1);
    var endDate = Date.parse(tempEndDate);

    //ensure that d1 is always 'smaller' than d2
    if(startDate<endDate)
    {
        //count is the number of working days
        var count = 0;
        var curDate = new Date(d1);
        var tempDay = curDate.getDay();
        var newStartDate = Date.parse(curDate);
        
        //uncomment to view outputs
        //window.alert(curDate);
        //window.alert(tempDay);
        //window.alert(newStartDate);
        //window.alert(endDate);

        //run the loop while start date is less than or equal to end date
        while (newStartDate <= endDate)
        {
            //when dayofWeek is not 6 or 0 i.e. Saturday and Sunday, increment count 
            if(!((tempDay === 6) || (tempDay === 0)))
            {
                count++;
            }
            
            //update the date by adding a new day to input date each iteration
            curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
            tempDay = curDate.getDay();
            newStartDate = Date.parse(curDate);
            
            //uncomment to view outputs.
            //window.alert(curDate);
            //window.alert(tempDay);
            //window.alert(newStartDate);
            //window.alert(endDate);
            //window.alert(count);
        }
        
        results = count;
    }
    else
    {
        //alert if d1 is greater than d2
        results = window.alert("ETA must be smaller than REQ.");
    }
    
    //return no. of working days
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Further clarification/Example:
If my starting date is set to 25/26, I should technically have 5 days after that but my output is only 4 days.

Comment: Try putting the `if(!((tempDay === 6) || (tempDay === 0)))` block beneath the other block in the `while`. I think that fixes your problem, but I'm unsure if it breaks something else

Comment: @Jb31 That actually did work. Could you explain a little why that works and not the other way around?

Comment: you are returning a global `results` from inside `weekdayCount` function - it still could return `undefined`...

Comment: What if `eta=="2020-07-31"` (while `req=="2020-07-31T10:33:21.000Z"`) - does this count as a day or not?  (assume it is a work day)

Comment: @iAmOren Yes, I was having the undefined issue. How to make sure that only one value is passed from `results`? 
And no, that does not count as a working day according to the requirements.